# ProgrammingError: close cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, tornado, psycopg2, gevent

I am getting this error when I am querying my rest app built with tornado, gevent, postgres and patched using psycogreen. I am constantly getting this error even when i am making requests at a concurrency of 10. If any one has a solution or info about what I might be doing wrong please share.

Error messages:

ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

ProgrammingError: close cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway

Stack Trace:

`File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2320, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2438, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2453, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 729, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 322, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 826, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 958, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1159, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 951, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 436, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) execute cannot be used while an asynchronous query is underway`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the same connection with two different cursors concurrently.